# Storing filename got using boost library in std::string variable

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I want to get the list of all files in a directory using boost::filesystem

I'm able to print the filenames using `cout` but i'm not able to store the filenames in a string variable. I have also tried type-casting and strcpy but none of the methods is working.

Following is the code :

```
char dir[100] = "/home/harsh/";
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

fs::directory_iterator start = fs::directory_iterator(dir);
fs::directory_iterator di = start;

for (; di != fs::directory_iterator(); ++di)
{
    std::cout << "hello .. " << di->path() << std::endl;

    //std::string strHarsh = di->path(); //Error
}
```

Comment: It helps to say what the error is. It does not compile (with an error message)? It crashes when run?

Comment: Looks like `Path` has a `c_str()` function, as well as a `string()` function.

Comment: I think you should also be able to do `di->path().native()` to get a `string` back. (Looking [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html))

Comment: I'd say you haven't really searched the [`path` class reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path).

Comment: @BoBTFish : It was a compilation error. "error: conversion from ‘const boost::filesystem3::path’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ requested"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `di->leaf()` it should convert to string

Also it depends on your version of boost, if you are using filesystem v3 it will be:
`di->path().filename().string()`

Comment: Boost library version is 1.49 . And i'm using filesystem v3

Comment: so I guess if you dereference the iterator you get this object: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_entry and then you can use the path to get the string you need

Comment: di->path().filename().string() worked perfectly !! Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) as intermediate:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << di->path();

std::string path = os.str();
```